# closed property of child is becoming true even child is not closed in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ1Lq.png)I am trying to listening to closed property of child in chrome but closed is becoming true even without closing the child tab. Below is the code I am using to achieve my task

```
    var child = window.open(
      "http://localhost:5001/auth/google",
      "",
      "location=yes,status=yes,width=1366,height=768"
    );
    const clearTimeout = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(child);
      if (child === null || child.closed) {
        clearInterval(clearTimeout);
        console.log("THE CHILD WINDOW HAS BEEN CLOSED");
      } else {
        console.log("OK");
      }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me except no clear interval because of missing variable. Please post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You haven't defined `clearTimeout` yet or defined it somewhere else.

Comment: @LãNgọcHải sorry i made a mistake while copying the code, i have edited it.

Comment: @MarkBaijens i have added the screenshot where we can see that my google popup window is opened but still gives me the console "THE CHILD WINDOW HAS BEEN CLOSED"

Comment: I believe you have the problem. However I can not reproduce your problem with the code given. Perhaps the page you call is the problem or you execute some other code that is causing it. Therefore my request to post a  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).